# check box helper not updating value in database Ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, checkbox

the checkbox helper isn't updating or inserting boolean values in the database.
A label has many attributes with values false as default and should become true when the checkbox is checked.but only the email attribute is being updated.

### labelscontroller

```
    def new 
    @label = current_user.labels.build
end

def create

    @label = current_user.labels.build(label_params)
    if @label.save
        redirect_to @label
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
def labels_params
params.require(:label).permit(:name,:email,:avatar,:nick,:intro)
end
```

### label/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @label, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal label" ,multipart: true} do |f| %>


  <div class="form-group", style="color: black;">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
     <%=f.error_span(:name) %>
  </div> <div class="form-group", style="color: black;">
    <%= f.label :email, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.check_box :email %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:email) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group", style="color: black;">
    <%= f.label :intro, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.check_box :intro, checked: false %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:intro) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                labels_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

### params

[developement.rb server logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlYDV.png)

### database values after the create commit

[rails console output of label when i ckecked both email and intro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkHKw.png)

Comment: note that in controller there is a typo.lables_params should be replaced with label_params.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and indent your code properly... You have tonnes of unnecessary/missing spaces, which makes the code so much harder to read!

Comment: Can you also try to cut this wayyyy down into a **minimal** example? What happens when you just do this: `Label.create(intro: '1')`

Comment: @TomLord hi I've reduced my code size.i tried using  Label.create(intro: '1' ) the intro attribute is still false.

Comment: OK good, so there's your **minimal** example! So now let's work out why this happens. Is there, for example, a `before_save` callback affecting this in the `Label` model? What happens if instead you try `Label.create(intro: true)`? What about `l = Label.new(intro: true)`, then check that `l.intro == true`, then `l.save`, then see if `l.label == false`.

Comment: @TomLord please refer to the following link for the response of  'Label.create(intro: '1')'  http://imgur.com/2PJNVWA

Comment: @TomLord,i've figured it out,there was an uncommented attr_accessor: intro line in label.rb.i commented out the line.now everything is working fine.Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Glad I could help point you in the right direction. In future, I advise that you take note of the StackOverflow guidelines on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Try to include as little irrelevant code as possible (such as your entire view file, or a long list of other permitted attributes in the controller), and try to make the question *complete* by proving all necessary information to reproduce the problem (in this case, the `Label` model).

Comment: sure will keep that in mind :)